# Key Press Connect at Start of Execution

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals, pyqt5, spacebars

I have a Python 3.6.3 script that incorporates PyQt5.  The GUI has a button that toggles play and pause of a video file.  Pressing the spacebar also toggles play and pause.  The button works fine all the time.  The spacebar also works as intended, except at the very start of executing the script.  I need to click some other event first (such as a button or slider bar) before the `spacebar` will correctly triggers the signal to pause or play the video.  I want to start playing the video with the `spacebar` when the script starts up.  Here is how I create the connections in the same `__init__(self)` function .  As you can see, clicking on the button and pressing the `spacebar` both connect the signal to the same function (`self.pauseVideo`).

```
self.btnPause = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
self.btnPause.clicked.connect(self.pauseVideo)

self.spacebar = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Space), self)
self.spacebar.activated.connect(self.pauseVideo)
```

Suggestions on how to get the `spacebar` to trigger the signal when the script first starts?

Comment: So you want to video to start when you open the tool? Why not just call the play function in the setupUI function?

Comment: No, I do not want the video to start playing upon open.  I want to use the spacebar to start playing the video instead of clicking the start or pause button.  I have keyboard shortcuts built in and prefer to use them rather than using the mouse.  All keyboard shortcuts work fine with this one minor exception that I'd like to fix.

Comment: So does the window have focus when you try to click space at the beginning? Like if you click only the title bar then space does that work? We may need to see the pauseVideo() code.

Comment: @slalomchip. This is impossible to answer unless you provide a [mcve]. There are any number of ways that the keyboard focus could be stolen by other widgets when the program starts up. Obviously the code in your question will work perfectly fine in a simple example with only one button.

Comment: I'll have to work on developing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  I understand why it is needed, but was hoping not to have to create it.  The current script is over 600 lines, not including the module QT Designer produced.  In the meantime, the ENTER key is also a shortcut to jump the video to a location and it does not have any problems.  I inserted a print statement into the pauseVideo() function - nothing printed, so pauseVideo() is never reached.  I inserted self.spacebar.setEnabled(True) into the __init__(), but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more searching, reassigning keyboard shortcuts (without success), etc., I found this post [PyQt widget keyboard focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046381/pyqt-widget-keyboard-focus).  I inserted

`self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)`

into `__init__(self)` and it seemed to solve my problem!  Now I'm just hoping it doesn't cause other issues.